# How do I retrieve all 60 years old above using birth_date in PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display all the customer where the age is 60 years old above by using the `birth_date`. The type of `bith_date` is `date`. This is the format of the `birth_date`-> `1999-03-12`. Can somebody help me with my problem?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_beneficiary` INNER JOIN tbl_barangay ON 
        tbl_beneficiary.barangay_id = tbl_barangay.barangay_id WHERE 
        tbl_beneficiary.is_active = 'No' AND (DATEDIFF(NOW(), 
        tbl_beneficiary.birth_date) <= 60) ORDER BY 
        tbl_beneficiary.beneficiary_id";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tested it but I think this ought to work ( it uses table aliases for ease of reading )

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_beneficiary` be
    INNER JOIN tbl_barangay ba ON be.barangay_id = ba.barangay_id 
WHERE 
    be.is_active = 'No' AND YEAR( FROM_DAYS( TO_DAYS( NOW() ) - TO_DAYS( be.birth_date ) ) ) > 60 
ORDER BY 
    be.beneficiary_id
```

Or, even simpler

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_beneficiary` be
    INNER JOIN tbl_barangay ba ON be.barangay_id = ba.barangay_id 
WHERE 
    be.is_active = 'No' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, be.birth_date, CURDATE()) > 60 
ORDER BY 
    be.beneficiary_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_beneficiary` INNER JOIN tbl_barangay ON 
        tbl_beneficiary.barangay_id = tbl_barangay.barangay_id WHERE 
        tbl_beneficiary.is_active = 'No' AND tbl_beneficiary.birth_date<=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 60 Years) ORDER BY 
        tbl_beneficiary.beneficiary_id";
```